# WordPress default page

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to wordpress world. I wanted to create multiple websites under one wordpress installation and for that I tried to do the setup with the localhost:81 port which wordpress doens’t allowed me since this process required the default local host installation. For that i stopped IIS which was installed with default port 80 and tried to edit apache httd.config and change the configuired port 81 with 80. It did start working. I also changed the port in wp-config.php file. WP then asked me to deactivate some plugins inorder to network setup i did the same but no luck whatsover. I wanted to undo all the changes and to some extent i am successfull but when I click on the home button of my website it redirect me to http://localhost/wordpress instead of http://localhost:81/wordpress

Your help is very much and direly needed.

Thanks,
Ghaffar

Comment: hi what operation system are you using?

Comment: Why are you trying to mess with ports when Multisite exists? https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: thanks manich and spartacus for your replies. I am using windows 10 64 bit os. well i already have configured iis and on that some websites are running and are accessible via the default port 80. Now since apache won't install with this port therefore i set 81 instead.

Comment: dear all, i resolved the issue by changing the wordpress name to someone else and now it redirect to actual default location and can be accessed from any link. i.e. http://localhost:81/mysite